# Convert roman numerals to decimal numbers

Tags: c

I write the following code to convert roman numbers to decimal numbers using C language but it is not giving the correct answers. I have done dry run also. please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num, newnum=0, result=0;

    printf("Enter number:");
    scanf("%s", &ch);

    while (ch != 'n') {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'i': num = 1; break;
        case 'v': num = 5; break;
        case 'x': num = 10; break;
        case 'l': num = 50; break;
        case 'c': num = 100; break;
        case 'd': num = 500; break;
        case 'm': num = 1000; break;
        }

        if (newnum > num) {
            result = result - num;
            newnum = num;
        } else {
            result = result + num;
            newnum = num;
        }
        printf("Enter number:");
        scanf("%s", &ch);
    }
    printf("%d", result);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a homework problem - if so you should mark it as so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Also see [the Rosetta Code page](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Roman_numerals/Decode#C) on this algorithm.

Comment: Save time.  Turn on all compiler warnings.  Your compiler should warning about `char ch; scanf("%s", &ch);`

Answer (score 0):

```
main()
```

should be written

```
int main( void )
```

This is not just a stylistic nit - as of C99, implicit typing is no longer allowed.

```
scanf("%s", &ch);
```

is not what you want here - the `s` conversion specifier expects `ch` to point to the first element of an *array* of `char`, not a single `char` object.  It tells `scanf` to read a *sequence* of non-whitespace characters and store them to a buffer, and it will write the zero terminator to the end of that buffer (i.e., to store a one-character *string*, you need a 2-element array of `char`).  As written, `scanf` will write to both `ch` and the byte immediately following it in memory, which may or may not have an effect elsewhere.

To read a *single* character from standard input, either use

```
scanf( " %c", &ch ); // note leading blank in format string; this tells scanf
                     // to skip over any leading whitespace characters
```

or

```
int ch;
...
ch = getchar(); // getchar returns int, not char
```

You might want to walk through your conversion algorithm on paper a few times.  What happens when you enter `i` followed by `v`?

Comment: Apart from compiling or logical error (wrong answers), it is giving run time error and printing input statement 2 times although i use               scanf("%c", &ch); .    Only running correctly on   ch=getche(); after including "conio.h" library.  Why?